# Javascript: Please explain the following code

Tags: javascript, function, closures

Here it is:

```
var add = (function () {
    var counter = 0;
    return function () {return counter += 1;}
})();
add();
add();
add();
// the counter is now 3
```

How it possible, that `counter` is `3` when it is set to `0` everytime `add` is called?

Comment: `add` is the function returned by the first function, not the first function itself (that's only called once). It might help to give the inner function a name: `return function inner () {return counter += 1;}`. When you call `add()` you are calling `inner()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`counter` is set to zero only **once**, while defining a new function in the instruction `var add = ....`

After this instruction, `add` is the function `function () {return counter += 1;}` (a bit complicated if you are new, see linked potential duplicate for a general explanation).

So, when you call add() thereafter, you call only the code that increment the counter.

This function has accesss to the variable counter (that's what we call a *closure*, more or less, the variable counter is not defined globally, it's not defined in the small `counter += 1` function, but it's nevertheless "taken with" the small function)